# How do I import Parse FacebookUtils?

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I'm upgrading my app from the FacebookUtilsV4 gem to Parse/FacebookUtils and struggling to import Parse FacebookUtils as a replacement.

Trying `#import <Parse/FacebookUtils.h>` but getting no luck. Any advice on how to fix? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out: `#import <Parse/PFFacebookUtils.h>`

Hopefully this helps someone else out too.